# Почему при использовании users.get выдает ошибку, о том что список пустой?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, vkontakte-api, telebot

Я отправляю сообщение боту с айди пльзователя или с его коротким именем, сообщение переходит в функцию `get_user_name` и при обработке сообщения создается список с помощью метода `users.get` в котором есть данные `first_name` и `last_name`, именно они и нужны мне для дальнейшей обаботки. Но когда идет обработка в `users.get`, то выдается ошибка в консоли: `list index out of range`, прошелся дебагом и оказалось, что список пуст, хотя я передал данные в метод, вот код:

````
def start(message):
    mess = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Введи айди")
    bot.register_next_step_handler(mess, get_user_name)

def get_user_name(user_id):
    name = session.method("users.get", {"user_id": user_id})
    bot.send_message(user_id.chat.id, f"{name[0]['first_name']}{name[0]['last_name']}")```
````

Comment: Наверное потому что список пустой...

Comment: Ну и у метода users.get не существует параметра user_id, читайте [документацию](https://dev.vk.com/method/users.get)

Comment: когда я хардкодил и вводил айди напрямую и выводил имя и фамилию на консоль, то этот метод работал и выдавал истинные данные о пользователе

Comment: А вас кстати не смущает, что `user_id` — это не число и даже не строка, а объект с телеграм-сообщением? Я как-то сильно сомневаюсь, что vkontakte api обучен принимать объекты вместо чисел и строк...

Comment: вот именно, что мне надо принимать сообщение отправленное пользователем в тг, и возможно как то сконвертировать его из тг сообщения в строку можно? чтобы потом эту же строку передать в функцию `get_user_name`

Comment: я только начинаю разбираться с vk api, поэтому не судите строго

Answer (score 0):

Как подсказали в комментах, список был пустой, т.к в него не передавались данные типа string или int, а передавался объект самого телеграмма, который как выяснилось, vk-api не может принять, и чтобы это заработало, я написал вот так:

````
def start(message):
    mess = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Введи айди")
    bot.register_next_step_handler(mess, get_user_name)

def get_user_name(message):
    name = session.method("users.get", {"user_ids": message.text})
    bot.send_message(user_id.chat.id, f"{name[0]['first_name']}{name[0]['last_name']}")```
````